# how to save more then 20 digit number in an integer in objective c Xcode any soluction

Tags: objective-c

i am develop a game in Xcode and my game score increase 20 digit like this(1000000000000000000000000) how to manage it help me.i want to store 20 digit number in integer and want to increase and decrease value in objective c

[image]

Comment: Please read first [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Apple provide the `NSDecimal` value type, and an object wrapped version of it `NSDecimalNumber`. This is a floating-point type with a precision of 38 decimal digits, so it can easily hold your 20 digit integer and do arithmetic on it.

If you'd rather stick with "pure" integers then a 128-bit integer type will more than suffice - it will represent 38 digit decimals. This is an optional type in C, `__int128` and `unsigned __int128`, and though the current Clang/Xcode compilers have the type there appears to be no built-in way to convert to/from strings for I/O - but converting an integer to a string is a simple algorithm you can implement yourself.

Another integer option is hidden inside of `CFNumber` which internally uses 128 bit integers. Apple release this as open source, [CFNumber.c](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-1153.18/CFNumber.c), and there are functions in there for addition, negation and conversion to text.

HTH